# Maximal component of a multivariate Gaussian distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian

Suppose you have a general  random Gaussian vector $\mathbf{X}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\right)$. I'm looking for the simple way to calculate the distribution of the maximal component: $P\left(\mathrm{argmax}_{i}X_{i}=k\right)$. Is there some closed-form expression, or a recursive formula for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145466

Comment: Carlo, thank you for pointing to this previous question. It is indeed highly related. However, I don't believe it is the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality, the problem is equivalent to computing the probability
$P(X_1 \geq \max(X_2, \ldots, X_n))$. We can transform the coordinates as $X_2-X_1, X_3-X_1, \ldots, X_n-X_1$ which is a fully general multivariate normal distribution of degree $n-1$. The problem is thus equivalent to finding the orthant probability for which there is no known closed-form solution for $n-1>3$

Comment: Arthur, thank you very much for your answer. Do you happen to have a reference for the last sentence?

Comment: Take your pick: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=multivariate+normal+orthant+closed+form

I don't think there is a proof that no closed-form solution exists, it's just that none is known and it seems very unlikely that one would exist.