# Lower bound for the probability that a certain component of a Gaussian vector dominates all others

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian

Let $X\sim\cal N(\mu,\Sigma)$ be an $n$-dimensional Gaussian vector. I would like to estimate $$P(X_1>\max_{k=2,\dots,n}X_k).$$

While no closed form solution exists (see e.g. MO question on [Maximal component of a multivariate Gaussian distribution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153039/maximal-component-of-a-multivariate-gaussian-distribution)), can one nevertheless obtain nontrivial lower bounds in the case that $\mu_1>\max_{k=2,\dots,n} \mu_k$?

Comment: You can translate this into a probability that another Gaussian vector is in the positive orthant, $(X_1-X_2, X_1-X_3,...,X_1-X_n)$. These probabilities have been studied.